# How can I set modalView in false?

Tags: function, react-native, if-statement, mobile, modalviewcontroller

I would like that on Click of a touchableopacity my app changes the modal state in false

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        modalVisible: true,
        first: true,
    }
}
checkIfFirstLog = () => {
    this.setState = {first: false}

    if (this.state.first = false) {
        this.setState = {
            modalVisible: false
        }
    }
}
<Modal           
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.checkIfFirstLog() }>

      </TouchableOpacity>   
 </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understand, you can use following code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        modalVisible: true,
        first: true,
    }
}
const checkIfFirstLog = () => {
    this.setState({
        modalVisible: true,
        first: true,
    });
}
<Modal           
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.checkIfFirstLog}>

    </TouchableOpacity>   
</Modal>
```

I merged two setState operations that you used in checkIfFirstLog method because you're already trying to change two state values as well. I think it would be good this way.